# Please help write a Test Class for method

Tags: apex, unit-test, test-setup

I am having difficulties writing a test class for the following method of mine and any help would be greatly appreciated:

```
//Method to filter opportunities based on SalesRep access

private Map<Id, Opportunity> filterSalesRepOpptys(List<Opportunity> lstOptyToFilter,Oppty_Search_IntegrationOperation.Oppty_SearchData seaData){
    Map<Id,Opportunity> mapOfOptys = new Map<Id,Opportunity>(lstOptyToFilter);

    Set<Id> setUnSortedOpptysIds = new Set<Id>();

    Map<Id, Opportunity> mapFilteredOpptys = new Map<Id, Opportunity>();
    List<Opportunity> limitedOpptys = new List<Opportunity>();
    List<User> salseRepbadgeID= null;
        salseRepbadgeID = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE IsActive=true and FederationIdentifier =:seaData.primarySalesRep limit 1];

    Id srid = salseRepbadgeID[0].Id;

    Map<Id,UserRecordAccess> mapURA = new Map<Id,UserRecordAccess>([SELECT RecordId FROM UserRecordAccess WHERE HasReadAccess = true AND UserId =:srid AND RecordId=:mapOfOptys.keyset()]);

    Integer count= 0;

    for(UserRecordAccess ura : mapURA.values()){
        setUnSortedOpptysIds.add(ura.RecordId);
    }

     //Sort the Opportunities on order
    if(mapURA!=null && mapURA.size()>0){
            for(Opportunity opp : lstOptyToFilter){
                if(setUnSortedOpptysIds.contains(opp.Id)){
                    //lstfilteredOpptys.add(opp);
                    mapFilteredOpptys.put(opp.id, opp);
                    System.debug('*** Adding to mapFilteredOpptys mapOfOptys.get(oppId).Name = ' + opp.Name);
                    count++;
                if(count==50){
                    break;
                }
                }
            }
    }
    //return all list of opportunities
    System.debug('*** Sending all Opptyes mapFilteredOpptys.values() = ' + mapFilteredOpptys);
    return mapFilteredOpptys;
}
```

Here is what i currently have:

```
@isTest
private class OpportunitySearch_Ali{
  static testMethod void OpportunitySearch_Ali_Svc()
  {
      Oppty_Search_IntegrationOperation.Oppty_SearchData opptySearchData = new Oppty_Search_IntegrationOperation.Oppty_SearchData();
      opptySearchData.opptyName= 'test';
      opptySearchData.opptyNo = '123';
      opptySearchData.soldToPartyNo = '1234';
      opptySearchData.endCustPartyNo = '1232';
      opptySearchData.tier2PartyNo = '123';
      opptySearchData.distributionChannel = 'Direct';
      Oppty_Search_IntegrationOperation.performOpptySearch( opptySearchData);

      List<Opportunity> oSR = [select Name from Opportunity where Name = 'test'];
      System.assertEquals(oSR.size(), 0);

      Oppty_Search_IntegrationOperation.Oppty_SearchData sData = new Oppty_Search_IntegrationOperation.Oppty_SearchData();
      sData.opptyName= 'test';
      sData.opptyNo = '123';
      sData.soldToPartyNo = '1234';
      sData.endCustPartyNo = '1232';
      sData.tier2PartyNo = '123';
      sData.distributionChannel = 'Direct';
      Oppty_Search_IntegrationOperation.performOpptySearch(sData);


    //Insert Account records
    List<Account> accList = new List<Account>();
    accList.add(new Account(Name = 'TestAcount0',Party_Number__c='111',ShippingCountry = 'United States'));
    accList.add(new Account(Name = 'TestAcount1',Party_Number__c= '222',ShippingCountry = 'United States'));
    accList.add(new Account(Name = 'TestAcount3',Party_Number__c= '333',ShippingCountry = 'United States'));
    accList.add(new Account(Name = 'TestAcount4',Party_Number__c= '444',ShippingCountry = 'United States'));
    insert accList;


    //Insert Opportunity records
    List<Opportunity> oppList = new List<Opportunity>();
    oppList.add(new Opportunity (Name = 'Test Opportunity ', AccountId = accList[0].id, Sales_Force__c = 'EMC',StageName = 'Pipeline',CloseDate = System.today(),Amount = 500, Opportunity_Number__c = '9999999',Quote_Cart_Number__c = '1000'));
    oppList.add(new Opportunity (Name = 'Test Opportunity 1', AccountId = accList[1].id, Sales_Force__c = 'EMC',StageName = 'Pipeline',CloseDate = System.today(),Amount = 600, Opportunity_Number__c = '8888888',Quote_Cart_Number__c = '1000'));
    oppList.add(new Opportunity (Name = 'Test Opportunity 2', AccountId = accList[2].id, Sales_Force__c = 'EMC',StageName = 'Pipeline',CloseDate = System.today(),Amount = 700, Opportunity_Number__c = '7777777'));
    oppList.add(new Opportunity (Name = 'Test Opportunity 3', AccountId = accList[3].id, Sales_Force__c = 'EMC',StageName = 'Pipeline',CloseDate = System.today(),Amount = 800, Opportunity_Number__c = '6666666',Quote_Cart_Number__c = '3000'));

    insert oppList;
    List<Opportunity> oppListQueried = new List<Opportunity>();
     oppListQueried = [ Select Id,Name,AccountId,Sales_Force__c,StageName,Amount,Opportunity_Number__c,Quote_Cart_Number__c from Opportunity order by Name];


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your test class, it seems like you have created the required test data.
Now you just have to call filterSalesRepOpptys method from your test class as shown below -
Add below code to your test class

```
  Test.startTest();
    filterSalesRepOpptys(//parametrers for this method);
    Test.stopTest();
```

Test.startTest() and Test.stopTest() method are used when tesing governor limits.

Use System.assert method to check whether you are getting the desired output.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  
  
I have added the following code to my test class but am getting an error:  
  
`filterSalesRepOpptys(oppList, opptySearchData);`  
  
This is the error that i'm receiving: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: filterSalesRepOpptys(List<Opportunity>, Oppty_Search_IntegrationOperation.Oppty_SearchData)  
  
Do you know what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Nevermind, I think i got it working now! Thanks again

Comment: ok, great. Let me know if you face any problem.